# OData: Do case insensitive comparison using ExpressionVisitor

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, expressionvisitor

For example, i have OData query such as these:

- /Suppliers?$filter=Address/City eq 'city'
- /Suppliers?$filter=contains(Address/City, 'city')
- /Suppliers?$filter=endswith(Address/City, 'city')

...

and Address/City only has "City". I still want the query to return that record.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428406/case-insensitive-string-compare-in-linq-expression) already but it only appear to address contains function. I could easily fix for other functions but eq is more difficult.
To make it simpler, i was thinking about just replacing all string const to uppercase by doing this .ToString().ToUpper().

I am having a problem because i can't really access the value.

```
protected override Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression node)
            {
//the node.Value i get here is {value(System.Web.OData.Query.Expressions.LinqParameterContainer+TypedLinqParameterContainer`1[System.String])} 
and of type System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression.
```

How can i either modify the value directly to upper case or add a call to ToString and ToUpper?

Comment: Have you tried the built-in [`tolower`](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc406398123) function? E.g., `/Suppliers?$filter=tolower(Address/City) eq 'city'`.

Comment: i don't have control over what queries are sent, they are constructed by users. I am able to change expression internally though

Comment: user21479 I have been working on the same issue, and I have an idea how to solve it, but what I don't know is how to plug the new Expression (result of the ExpressionVisitor) into the query pipeline.

Answer (score 3):

The ideal solution would be to handle this on the client side with the built-in [`tolower`](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc406398123) and [`toupper`](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc406398124) filter functions. That would allow the client to make the choice whether to filter with or without case-sensitivity.

On the server side, current best practice is, unfortunately, to modify the request URI and generate a new request object for the modified URI. See [OData V4 modify $filter on server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33660648/odata-v4-modify-filter-on-server-side). There is an open issue in Web API OData for a more elegant [query option interception/modification mechanism](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/357).

Doing string surgery directly on the request URI is always going to be error-prone. We can improve on the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33684667/1257889) by taking advantage of the rich object model for filter expressions in the [OData Library](https://github.com/OData/odata.net) (ODL). Note that the filter expression on `ODataQueryOptions.Filter.FilterClause.Expression` is an abstract syntax tree representing the value of `$filter`.

The code that follows requires namespaces from ODL:

```c
using Microsoft.OData.Core;
using Microsoft.OData.Core.UriBuilder;
using Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser;
using Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.Semantic;
using Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.TreeNodeKinds;
using Microsoft.OData.Edm;
```

First, define a helper class for rewriting the various nodes that make up a filter AST. The following class currently only handles `BinaryOperatorNode` (e.g., `eq` expressions).

```c
public static class FilterExpressionHelper
{
    public static SingleValueNode RewriteAsCaseInsensitive(BinaryOperatorNode node)
    {
        // Handle {Edm.String eq Edm.String}
        if (node.OperatorKind == BinaryOperatorKind.Equal && node.Left.TypeReference.IsString() && node.Right.TypeReference.IsString())
        {
            // Wrap both operands with toupper().
            node = new BinaryOperatorNode(BinaryOperatorKind.Equal,
                new SingleValueFunctionCallNode("toupper", new List<QueryNode> { node.Left }, node.Left.TypeReference),
                new SingleValueFunctionCallNode("toupper", new List<QueryNode> { node.Right }, node.Right.TypeReference));
        }

        return node;
    }

    // Add methods to handle other node types; e.g., SingleValueFunctionCallNode.
}
```

Next, define a helper to invoke the rewriter and regenerate the query string of the request URI (as modeled by `ODataQueryOptions`).

```c
public class ODataUriHelper
{
    public static string RewriteQuery(ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
    {
        var odataUri = BuildODataUri(queryOptions);
        var uriBuilder = new ODataUriBuilder(ODataUrlConventions.Default, odataUri);
        var uri = uriBuilder.BuildUri();
        // Do not return the leading '?'.
        return uri.Query.Substring(1);
    }

    private static readonly Uri DummyServiceRoot = new Uri("http://localhost");
    private static readonly ODataPath DummyPath = new ODataPath(Enumerable.Empty<ODataPathSegment>());

    private static ODataUri BuildODataUri(ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
    {
        var uri = new ODataUri();

        uri.ServiceRoot = DummyServiceRoot;
        uri.Path = DummyPath;
        uri.Filter = RewriteFilter(queryOptions.Filter?.FilterClause);
        uri.OrderBy = queryOptions.OrderBy?.OrderByClause;
        uri.SelectAndExpand = queryOptions.SelectExpand?.SelectExpandClause;
        uri.Skip = queryOptions.Skip?.Value;
        uri.Top = queryOptions.Top?.Value;

        return uri;
    }

    private static FilterClause RewriteFilter(FilterClause filterClause)
    {
        if (filterClause != null)
        {
            var filterExpr = filterClause.Expression;
            var binaryExpr = filterExpr as BinaryOperatorNode;

            if (binaryExpr != null)
            {
                filterExpr = FilterExpressionHelper.RewriteAsCaseInsensitive(binaryExpr);
                filterClause = new FilterClause(filterExpr, filterClause.RangeVariable);
            }

            // Add support for other node types here.
        }

        return filterClause;
    }
}
```

Finally, tie it all together with a custom version of the `EnableQuery` attribute that conditionally performs rewriting.

```c
public class CustomEnableQueryAttribute : EnableQueryAttribute
{
    public override IQueryable ApplyQuery(IQueryable queryable, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
    {
        if (queryOptions.Filter != null)
        {
            var query = ODataUriHelper.RewriteQuery(queryOptions);
            var uri = new UriBuilder(queryOptions.Request.RequestUri) { Query = query };
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri.Uri);

            queryOptions = new ODataQueryOptions(queryOptions.Context, request);
        }

        return base.ApplyQuery(queryable, queryOptions);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
?$filter=contains(tolower(siteName),tolower(%27michel%27))
                           ---^---            ---^---
                            Field           value to find

?$filter=contains(tolower(siteName),tolower(%27Michel%27))
?$filter=contains(tolower(siteName),tolower(%27MiCHel%27))
```